# How to maintain magento 1.4.1.1 database to magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: database, magento

I have two domains:

```
1.main domain  : which have magento 1.4.1.1 site
2.sub domain   : which have magento 1.7.0.2 site(this site is upgraded from magento 1.4.1.1)
```

That means in my sub domain it had magento1.4.1.1 magento as in the main domain in past.

Then i uprgaded the magento site to 1.7.0.2 in sub domain.

The client now using the main domain and they use the old databse.

In my sub domain i have new database and i imported the db backup .
But this backup was taken from before two months.
That means the db backup is two months old.
So in main domain ,the client enter new datas into the old database.
After importing databse in subdomain i upgraded the site to 1.7.0.2

So i want to put all changes in the old database to new databse.

```
The old database have 329 tables and new database have 367 tables
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3):

The best option in your case:

1. Get dump of old database.
2. Setup the copy of the new codebase on another subdomain.
3. Load dump into new database and point newly created subdomain codebase to it.
4. Magento will automatically update the structure of the database.
5. If any error appear during upgrading of old database to new one, you can fix it without letting old website down (separate db, separate instance). If no errors were found, you can turn off old website, upgrade db, and upload new code base.

Comment: @Ivn ,i dont have permission to create a new sub domain.So can i test it on my localhost

Comment: Sure you can test it on your localhost.

Comment: @Ivn ,1.i created a db with old dump.2.Then i take the new upagraded url in browser.3.But igot some errors.In new db only 7 tables are imported.

Comment: @Ivn ,the old dump means you , the the db with 329 tables.is it?

Comment: Hi Mariya, yes, old dump means db with 329, if you get errors, try to check your customizations that causing db upgrading errors. After fixing issues in customizations try to re-upgrade it again (from beginning) to be sure that it won't break live environment.

Comment: @ Ivan, now i imported the db,but my site messed up.Bcz the checkout page displays blank page.Can you give me a solution for thta?

Comment: check the error logs of php and apache. It should give you a hint where to look for an error.

Comment: @ Ivan , there have no clue about that,and i have no client's ssh details.I also tried in index.php to get errors ,but it doesnot displays any errors.

Comment: Set development mode to yes and uncomment ini_set('display_errors', 1); line.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15311/discussion-between-mariya-davis-and-ivan-chepurnyi)

Comment: @ Ivan, i got this error when i follow your instruction
Fatal error: Call to a member function setStore() on a non-object in /hsphere/local/home/davidson/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Shipping.php on line 421

Comment: @ Ivan ,missed some thing.bcz there is need to  print the flat shipping price when click check out

Comment: You have not all the extensions installed at old version that is on main domain on your subdomain. That's why you have issues.